# Complex menu on Toolbar item

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-appcompat

How to achieve something like this using ListPopupWindow?

[image]

I've tried to get the Item View instance on onOptionsItemSelected, so while in onCreateOptionsMenu it was returning null (as you can See the comment line):

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_socials, menu);    //        The line bellow was returning null
//        ImageButton view = (ImageButton) menu.findItem(R.id.fake_overflow).getActionView();
        listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
                getContext());
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(
                getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, products));
        listPopupWindow.setWidth(300);
        listPopupWindow.setHeight(400);
        listPopupWindow.setModal(true);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fake_overflow);
//        listPopupWindow.show();
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("TAG","action click?");
                listPopupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: you can try creating a custom popup menu

Comment: its the new overflow menu new look in new support lib appcompat-v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) which is also available on the support library. As the name says, the `PopupWindow` is wrapped around a List(View) and it accepts an Adapter. Using a custom adapter you should be able to customize the look&feel of each row easily. The overflow view will be the anchor view of your `ListPopupWindow`

Comment: I was able to change for a  ListPopupWindow, setting its anchor by the item view as it follows: 
` @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fake_overflow);
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(view);
        listPopupWindow.show();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }`